# How do i get a service worker detected & registered in web2py?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, web2py

I am trying to create a web2py progressive app but so far in all I have done Chrome Developer Tools keeps showing a warning message that says :

**"No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload page or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope of the start URL from the manifest."**

I have placed the service worker and the main.js file in `{{=URL('static','js/')}}` directory.

In my research I came across some information saying that I have to place the service worker in a root directory but I dont know where to locate the root directory in this framework!

Please assist me in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have registered your service worker correctly and your main.js include in index.html

For better answer post service worker register code and index.html so it will be better to understand.

Thanks

Comment: **Service Worker Register:**<br /> `if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/init/static/js/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}`

Comment: **Layout Code for the HTML:** `<link rel="manifest" href="/init/static/manifest/manifest.json">
  
    <!-- The javascript =============================== -->
    <script src="{{=URL('static','js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{=URL('static','js/web2py-bootstrap4.js')}}"></script>
  <script src="/init/static/js/main.js"></script>`

Comment: @sesoasesoa Please verify "'/init/static/js/sw.js'" this path and if possible then keep sw.js in app folder so try to avoid relative path and make sure service worker code is not wrong